# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to k}\frac{x^n+ax+b}{x-k}$, where $k$ is a roots of $x^n+ax+b=0$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> If $a_1,a_2,..,a_n$ are the roots of the equation $x^n+ax+b=0$ then find $(a_1-a_2)(a_1-a_3)....(a_1-a_n)$

**My Attempt**

$$
x^n+ax+b=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)...(x-a_n)=0\\
(x-a_2)(x-a_3)...(x-a_n)=\frac{x^n+ax+b}{x-a_1}\\
(a_1-a_2)(a_1-a_3)....(a_1-a_n)=\lim_{x\to a_1}(x-a_2)(x-a_3)...(x-a_n)\\
=\lim_{x\to a_1}\frac{x^n+ax+b}{x-a_1}
$$
My reference gives the solution $na_1^{n-1}+a$. I can use L'Hospital's rule
$$
\lim_{x\to a_1}\frac{x^n+ax+b}{x-a_1}=\lim_{x\to a_1}\frac{nx^{n-1}+a}{1}=na_1^{n-1}+a
$$

But how do I evaluate the limit directly ?

Comment: Take $n=1$, $a=0$, $b=k=1$ to see that you claim is wrong.

Comment: The question has given unclear instruction. In your case, you suppose the polynomial $x^n+ax+b$ has a root of $k$, so the limit is in indeterminate form of $0/0$ when substituting $k$ for $x$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to k}\frac{x^n+ax+b}{x-k}=nk^{n-1}+a$ iff $k^n+ak+b=0$. Otherwise, it is $\infty$. If $k^n+ak+b=0$, $\lim_{x\to k}\frac{x^n+ax+b}{x-k}=\lim_{x\to k}\frac{x^n-k^n+ax-ak+b-b}{x-k}=a+\lim_{x\to k}\frac{x^n-k^n}{x-k}=nk^{n-1}+a$

Comment: Your RHS is the derivative of the numerator evaluated at $k$. We can imagine that you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @weilam06 I have edited OP to include the context where I had to consider the following limit. Pls check

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry for that, I have added more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any differentiable function $f(x)$, if $r$ is a root of $f$, then

$$\lim_{x\to r}\frac{f(x)}{x-r}=\lim_{x\to r}\frac{f(x)-f(r)}{x-r}=f'(r),$$ by the definition of the derivative.

Comment: I think I am confused with how $\lim_{x\to r}\frac{f(x)}{x-r}=\lim_{x\to r}\frac{f(x)-f(r)}{x-r}$ ?. in this case ?

Comment: @ss1729: hem, what is $f(r)$ ?

Comment: Alright. $\lim_{x\to r}\frac{x^n+ax+b}{x-r}=\lim_{x\to r}\frac{(x^n+ax+b)-(r^n+ar+b)}{x-r}=f'(r)$ right ?.

Comment: @ss1729: so what is $f(r)$ ?

Comment: $f(r)=r^n+ar+b$ which got to be zero as $r$ is one of the roots right?

Answer (score 1):

The claim you are trying to prove is wrong. For example, if $k=0$, the expression in the limit becomes $$\frac{x^n+ax+b}{x} = x^{n-1} + a + \frac bx$$ and the limit of this does not exist if $b\neq 0$.

In general, the limit will not exist whenever $k^n + ak + b$ is different from $0$, since in that case, the numerator tends to a nonzero number and the denominator tends to $0$.

If $k^n+ak+b=0$, then you can use that fact to write $x^n+ax+b$ as a product of $(x-k)$ and some other polynomial (remember, $k$ is a root of polynomial $p$ if and only if $p$ is divisible by $(x-k)$!)

Comment: I have edited OP, please check.

Comment: @ss1729 Here's another hint. To divide a polynomial by a polynomial of degree $1$, a certain mister Horner came up with a rather nifty method...

Answer (score 0):

Observe that we have

$$\lim_{x\to k}\frac{x^n+ax+b}{x-k}=nk^{n-1}+a  \iff k^n+ak+b=0.$$

So , $\lim_{x\to k}\frac{x^n+ax+b}{x-k}=nk^{n-1}+a $ is not true , if $k^n+ak +b \ne 0.$

Comment: I have edited the post, hope the question is well explained now.